# docker-compose network creation kicks me out of ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, docker-compose

I need help understanding my networking logs due to `docker-compose` networking.

I'm ssh'd into a **VM**, and I have two projects with docker-compose. The first is launched simply with `docker-compose up`. When I try to launch the second, my ssh session freezes, and I can no longer ssh into the VM. After lots of trial and error, and after reading [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/using-a-pre-existing-network) I tried to append to my 2nd project's `docker-compose.yml` file the following:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: abcdef_default
```

where `abcdef_default` is the name of the network created by `docker-compose up` of the 1st project. With this, the `docker-compose up` on the 2nd project doesn't kick me out of the ssh session.

I tailed the logs in `/var/log/*.log`, and here's the output *with* the networks section in the `docker-compose.yml` file (without the timestamp prefix: `Jan 19 09:13:42 hostname kernel: [420096.305357]`):

```
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[13813]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
device veth6a84537 entered promiscuous mode
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth6a84537: link is not ready
eth0: renamed from veth2480623
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth6a84537: link becomes ready
br-fe0deb0149df: port 18(veth6a84537) entered forwarding state
br-fe0deb0149df: port 18(veth6a84537) entered forwarding state
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[25317]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
device veth1a3c1e3 entered promiscuous mode
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth1a3c1e3: link is not ready
br-fe0deb0149df: port 22(veth1a3c1e3) entered forwarding state
br-fe0deb0149df: port 22(veth1a3c1e3) entered forwarding state
eth0: renamed from veth54e576d
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth1a3c1e3: link becomes ready
br-fe0deb0149df: port 22(veth1a3c1e3) entered disabled state
veth54e576d: renamed from eth0
br-fe0deb0149df: port 22(veth1a3c1e3) entered disabled state
device veth1a3c1e3 left promiscuous mode
br-fe0deb0149df: port 22(veth1a3c1e3) entered disabled state
br-fe0deb0149df: port 18(veth6a84537) entered forwarding state
```

and here's the output *without* the `networks` section (i.e. when I get kicked out of the ssh session):

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-55349b03453a: link is not ready
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[26982]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[26982]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[3051]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
device veth7a1bcde entered promiscuous mode
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth7a1bcde: link is not ready
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered disabled state
eth0: renamed from veth5d8a2ea
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth7a1bcde: link becomes ready
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered forwarding state
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-55349b03453a: link becomes ready
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[13814]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[13814]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[13922]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
device veth3253bd4 entered promiscuous mode
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth3253bd4: link is not ready
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered disabled state
eth0: renamed from veth9c8aaa3
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth3253bd4: link becomes ready
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered disabled state
veth9c8aaa3: renamed from eth0
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered disabled state
device veth3253bd4 left promiscuous mode
br-55349b03453a: port 2(veth3253bd4) entered disabled state
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered forwarding state
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered disabled state
veth5d8a2ea: renamed from eth0
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered disabled state
device veth7a1bcde left promiscuous mode
br-55349b03453a: port 1(veth7a1bcde) entered disabled state
```

I don't really understand how to read these logs.
[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23826643/) is my `ifconfig` also.
Can someone help me read the logs and figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Diagnosis

Our team is using AWS EC2 instances running Ubuntu 18.04 as devservers. We recently got reports that docker-compose broke SSH connections. Even after restarting, the devservers are still inaccessible. So I started investigation.

I was able to exclude the cause of docker-compose by reproducing using docker only.

```sh
ubuntu@ip-172-31-115-116:~$ docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
aca5884d60f146cef81ac55c8cccd231a43f40927d645168642d9b28c5e009a6

ubuntu@ip-172-31-115-116:~$ docker network prune
WARNING! This will remove all custom networks not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Networks:
my-bridge-network

ubuntu@ip-172-31-115-116:~$ docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
f0a7a06a9627bc2de00eb60091a92010451690626d95e077f622f3058cc3a07c

ubuntu@ip-172-31-115-116:~$ docker network prune
WARNING! This will remove all custom networks not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Networks:
my-bridge-network

ubuntu@ip-172-31-115-116:~$ docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
Connection reset by 172.31.115.116 port 22
```

Then the root cause occurred to me.

### Root cause

- Our docker-compose files are using the bridge network mode which will create a new bridge network by default. When `docker-compose down` or `docker network prune` is run, the bridge network will be torn down. And the next `docker-compose run` or `docker network create` will create a new bridge network.
- The default IP range for the docker0 bridge adapter is `172.17.0.0/16`.
- When I first ran the `docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network`  command, it created a new bridge adapter for `172.18.0.0/16`.
- The second bridge adapter was created for `172.19.0.0/16`.
- Naturally, the 3rd bridge adapter is created for `172.20.0.0/16`.  However, that is our Engineering VPN IP range. Therefore the overlap caused the server unable to communicate with our laptop.

### Solutions

The solution is to make sure new docker bridge networks will skip our VPN IP range.

### Temp solution

If we add the skipped IP ranges to system route table, docker will automatically skip them. Therefore, we can run the below script whenever the devserver got rebooted.

```sh
sudo route add -net [our VPN IP range] netmask 255.255.0.0 gw [our gateway]
```

This solution is imperfect that the new routes will be discarded after restarting the machine.

#### Main solution

We should permanently apply the route changes to all devservers.

```sh
echo "            routes:" | sudo tee -a /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
echo "            - to: [our VPN IP range]" | sudo tee -a /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
echo "              via: [our gateway]" | sudo tee -a /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
sudo netplan apply
```

#### Docker IP changes

We also plan to modify the docker default-address-pools to redefine docker IP ranges. Refer to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4336#issuecomment-457326123. I would say modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json` is better.

Comment: Thanks for posting all the details. I marked your answer as the accepted one since my own was just a very crude workaround without understanding what was really going on

Answer (score 4):

br-*xxxxxxx* are the bridge interfaces of Docker and veth*xxxxxxx* are the virtual interfaces of your containers, Docker use those veth interfaces but you do not directly interact on it, they use an IPv6 address and don't have IPv4.

Docker can't create NAT interfaces, it can only create bridge and veth with IPv6 for containers. You can link your bridge to any physical or virtual interface of your host.

So it work like that:

**eth0** (your interface or v-interface if you want) **↔ br*xxxxx***(docker bridge) ↔ **veth*xxxxx*** (virtual interface of your container)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Comparing the logs, the only 2 differences I can see are that the port numbers 18/22 in the successful case are different than the ports 1/2 in the failed case. Also, it seems some lines are duplicated in the logs. Do you think these two points could relate to me being kicked out of the ssh session? My ssh session is over port 22, but the case when port 22 appears in the logs is the case when I do NOT get kicked out.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I solved it by setting the `network_mode` option on docker compose (see the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode). The solution came from [this thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3012) ).

```
services:
  my_service:
    image: ...
    network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: This disables the ability of using container names when connecting between containers

Answer (score 3):

I finally ended up running a `docker network ls`. The output was a list of more than 15 networks which were very old. I ran a `docker ps` to make sure that nothing related to these networks was still running. One container was indeed still running (redis) and it was on a network called `bridge`. I stopped the container. Then I started going through all the networks with `docker network rm <network name>` until I was left with 4 networks: bridge, host, none, and the only network that was still working. Then I could start new networks with `docker-compose up` again as usual